# Sending message to private Telegram channel fails using Bot API python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

I have tried sending message to a telegram channel using Telegram's BOT API with Python 3.11.0.

At first I have tried making the channel Public and the code worked fine:

```
import requests

# Replace YOUR_BOT_TOKEN with your actual bot token
bot_token = BOT_API_KEY

# Replace YOUR_CHAT_ID with the chat ID of the recipient
chat_id = '@testme100'

# The message you want to send
text = 'Hello, world!'

# The URL for the Telegram Bot API
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage'

# The data to be sent in the POST request
data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': text}

# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Message sent successfully.')
else:
    print(f'Error sending message: {response.text}')
```

The output:
[image: output of the code]

But then I thought of making it private channel and changed the Channel ID:
The URL is : `https://t.me/+vMjFCXBghv00NDZl` and I thought the text ahead of `+` is the channel ID, so I changed the `chat_id = '@vMjFCXBghv00NDZl'`.

But now it's not sending the messages to the channel. When I make it public again then it works fine.

The error I received = `Error sending message: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}`

Answer (score 2):

The invite link **is not** the same as the `chat_id`.

Public channels do allow sending messages using the `@channel-name`, but that's not a replacement of the `chat_id`, that will still work.

To send messages from the bot to the private channel, you can only use the `chat_id`.

There are tons of ways of getting this, I always forward a message from the channel to an echo bot (one that just response with the json from Telegram).

<sub>(For example, this bot: https://t.me/chatIDrobot, the first you find if you search for 'echo bot')</sub>

Then use the ID provided to send messages

Comment: Thank you for sharing your response. I would like to know if there is any way I could get the Chat id at runtime because I am trying to maintain different bots and channels using a script. So I think if I can get the ID of the channels at runtime and fast then it could be very easy for me to send the message to any channel irrespective of the public or private.

Comment: Well, if your bot has access to the messages in the channel, he will get an update when a message is send. In this update, the channel ID can be found. Only requirement is that the bot is in the channel before a message is send.

Comment: But I want ID for sending the messages. what you are suggesting is after sending the message. How I can send message if I do not have the chat id and I need to obtain it somehow?

Comment: Sorry, not the bot, but an user, could be anybody in the channel. The bot will then receive that message with the channel's id.

Comment: Okay means I have to message manually first so that the bot gets to know the channel id. Got it. I was thinking to get everything automatic but if there is need for the manual intervention then I will do that way. Thank you for your answer.